# Kotlin: filterNotNull() and withIndex() but preserve pre-filter index

Tags: kotlin

I have a `val foo: List<Foo?>` that contains some nullable values. I'd like to convert it to something like `List<IndexedValue<Foo>>` where the null values are filtered out but it has the *original* index.

For example,
`val foo: List<String?> = listOf("a", null, "b")`
should become something like
`bar: List<Int, String> = [(0, "a"), (2, "b")]`

Some things I tried would still end up as `List<Int, String?>` even after filtering null values. The best I could come up with that seems to work is:

```
foo.mapIndexedNotNull {index, v -> v?.let {index to v}}
```

Is there anything a bit more direct?

Comment: You might actually want a [SparseArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/util/SparseArray)

Comment: Your code actually produces list of pairs `bar: List<Pair<Int, String>>`. `List<Int, String?>` isn't even legal since List only takes 1 generic type parameter

Answer (score 0):

As Ricky Mo mentioned you can use the sparse array here, something like this

```
val sparseArray = SparseArray<Foo>()

    foo.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
        value?.let { sparseArray.put(index, it) }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have the problem that the result has elements of type `String?` instead of `String` ?
The problem is here inside the `v?.let` scope function. It does not change the 'v', it makes only the block parameter to a null safe string.
So you need to use it as following:

```
 v?.let{ safeV: String -> index to safeV }
```

or a little simpler:

```
 v?.let{ index to it }
```